# Looking for an error in my Modbus Console.WriteLine

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp, minimalmodbus

I have this C# Code, and it is producing an error on the `Console.WriteLine($"Register {startAddress + i}={registers[i]}");` line. I have tried double `))`, and placed it everywhere in the statement. I simply cannot see where the error is. I am probably missing something simple and I'm just not seeing it.

```
    namespace NModbus.TestDriver

{
    using System;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using Modbus.Device;
    using NModbus;


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                         using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.111.169", 502))
                {
                    client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);

                    var master = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(client);
                    // read five input values
                  byte slaveId = 1;
                ushort startAddress = 1;
                ushort numRegisters = 5;

                // read five registers      
                ushort[] registers = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, numRegisters);

                for (int i = 0; i < numRegisters; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Register {startAddress + i}={registers[i]}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "having an error" - please include the error message in your question (the line [works OK](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dX4Vbc) for me). Probably better to tag this with `c#` and remove the modbus tags (you are using modbus but the issue you face does not appear to be modbus related).

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the string before doing `Console.WriteLine` -- so the for loop is like this

```
             for (int i = 0; i < numRegisters; i++)
                {
                    string whateverName = $"Register {startAddress + i}={registers[i]}"
                    Console.WriteLine(whateverName);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace NModbus.TestDriver

{
    using System;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using NModbus;
    using Modbus.Device;


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.111.169", 502))
                {
                    client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);

                    var master = ModbusIpMaster.CreateIp(client);
                    // read five input values
                    byte slaveId = 1;
                    ushort startAddress = 1;
                    ushort numRegisters = 5;

                    // read five registers      
                    ushort[] registers = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveId, startAddress, numRegisters);

                    for (int i = 0; i < numRegisters; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Register {startAddress + i}={registers[i]}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Can u try like this and say to your ex message ?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**